# Inline string init from an array

Tags: c#

So I am using:

```
fileName.Split(' ');
```

And I am wondering if I can init the strings inline, ie:

```
string a, b, c, d = fileName.Split(' ');
```

So if file name is "1 2 3 4", I would expect this:

```
a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) returns `string[]`. This has nothing to do with inline declaration.

Short answer: **No**.

Answer (score 4):

Until Split() actually evaluates the string, you can't possibly know how many tokens it will return.

So even if this syntax was supported, it would be extremely vulnerable to null references (you provided too many variables).  Even worse, what should be done if you don't provide enough variables?

Comment: This was exactly what I was thinking too. You would need to be 100% sure you will only ever have a fixed or finite array size. IndexOutOfRange exceptions and NullReference exceptions would be a big probability.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that syntax isn't supported by C#. You'll have to do it the "long" way. :(

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with working with the separate strings as elements of the array,

Eg

```
string[] a = fileName.Split(' ');
```

The variables you would use would be `a[0] = 1, a[1] = 2...`

Comment: In C#, your array should be declared as `string[]`, not `string()`.

Comment: @JonSenchyna: Taa - Guess who's writing a VB.Net system right now!

Comment: I was guessing it was something like that.

Comment: Indexing is with `[` instead of `(` as well (`a[0]`, `a[1]`, ...)

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Fixed that too.